# Create bootable usb with mojave from UBUNTU

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot, mac, usb

I have downloaded dmg file with mojave.

I got usb flash stick (8 gb). Formatted it to hfs+
Converted dmg to iso and have burned it with dd command. But my mac doesn't recognize that bootable usb. Is it possible to create bootable usb stick in ubuntu or other linux operation system? I see tutorials only from mac, that's strange... I have formatted my mac and now it doesn't has OS on it.

Comment: This is all a bit confused... Macs won't boot from either the .dmg or it simply converted to be an .iso, the boot/install media is 'inside' that dmg, it's not bootable on its own. Secondly, how is it 'not recognising' it? You hold Opt at boot... then what? Thirdly ... can you not just reinstall from Internet Recovery?

Comment: Internet recovery works just fine! Solved :)